# MaterialDesignThemes ComboBox Selected Item template issue

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, material-design-in-xaml

I'm working on styling a WPF ComboBox so that the ComboBoxItems have some additional data. The items look great when in the drop down, but once selected, the displayed item is not stretched/filling the ComboBox- it's all smushed to the left. I've done enough digging to figure out this is related to the MaterialDesign Theme being applied to the control. Without MeterialDesign being referenced in a demo project, the code works as anticipated.

```xml
<ComboBox Width="150" 
        Margin="2" 
                  
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" <!-- No Effect //-->
                  
        materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Select Item"
                  
        ItemsSource="{StaticResource ExampleItems}" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding DisplayText}" />

                <Ellipse Grid.Column="1" Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{Binding Color}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

    <!-- No Effect //-->
    <!--<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignComboBoxItemStyle}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>-->
</ComboBox>
```

[image: Incorrect Selected Item and Correct drop down items]

I've tried pretty much everything I can without luck- Including various controls inside the DataTemplate, stack panel, dock panel, etc....

I've created a minimum reproducible example here: [ComboBoxDemo Project](https://github.com/AndyStagg/ComboBoxDemo)

I've included the ComboBox Style I pulled from Blend, to try to dig into what MaterialDesign is doing on top of the normal template. I see that there is an ItemContainerStyle for the selected item, but it looks like it's binding the HorizontialContentAlignment up the chain. Manually setting that to Stretch did not help.

So Hopefully a Xaml guru out there can pinpoint the issue...

Comment: Works fine for me without `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`.

Comment: The regular non-material design combobox works correctly. Once material design is in play, the selected item content is not stretched across the width of the combobox.